# Creating sub array from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$test = array
(
    "0" => array
        (
            "isLibrary" => 1,
            "isActive" => 1,
            "title" => "Mytitle1234",
            "nps" => 750000001456,
            "system" => "Remote",
            "system_path" =>"./remote/system/test"
        ),
    "1" => array
        (
            "isLibrary" => 1,
            "isActive" => 1,
            "title" => "Mytitle1234",
            "nps" => 750000001456,
            "system" => "Local",
            "system_path" =>"./local/system/test"
        )
)
```

This is my array. Is there any predefined function in PHP so that I can get the result as below.

```
$test = array
    (
        "0" => array
            (
                "isLibrary" => 1,
                "isActive" => 1,
                "title" => "Mytitle1234",
                "nps" => 750000001456,
                "locations" => array (
                        "Remote" => array (
                             "system" => "Remote",
                             "system_path" =>"./remote/system/test"
                             ),
                        "local" => array (
                             "system" => "Local",
                             "system_path" =>"./local/system/test"
                             )
                  )
             )
```

I want to combine the array and want to make subarray based on system value.

Comment: Why down vote. Wanted to know any predefined function available

Comment: I assume, it's because you have not included any attempts or code. Only the arrays. But I don't know. I didn't downvote

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_diff to separate the parts you want then build the new array from these parts.

```
$remote = array_diff($test[0], $test[1]);
$local = array_diff($test[1], $test[0]);

//what is not "remote", meaning the start of the array
$new[] = array_diff($test[0], $remote); 
// Add remote and local
$new[0]["locations"] =["remote" => $remote, "local" => $local];

Var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/KHlu8

Edit: Forgot the 0 index, added [] and [0].

---

If you don't know for sure if remote or local is in [0] you can use this code.

```
$temp = array_diff($test[0], $test[1]);
$locations["locations"][$temp["system"]] = $temp; 
$temp = array_diff($test[1], $test[0]);
$locations["locations"][$temp["system"]] = $temp; 


$new[] = array_diff($test[0], $locations["locations"][$test[0]["system"]]);
$new[0] =array_merge($new[0], $locations);

Var_dump($new);
```

It saves what is the difference in a temp array and then builds the locations array from what is in the locations array.

https://3v4l.org/BNQXZ

Answer (score -1):

A predefined function won't create your custom array for you, but here's how to build it up.

```
<?php

$old = 
[
    [
        "isLibrary" => 1,
        "isActive" => 1,
        "title" => "Mytitle1234",
        "nps" => 750000001456,
        "system" => "Remote",
        "system_path" =>"./remote/system/test"
    ],
    [
        "isLibrary" => 1,
        "isActive" => 1,
        "title" => "Mytitle1234",
        "nps" => 750000001456,
        "system" => "Local",
        "system_path" =>"./local/system/test"
    ],
];

$new = [
    "isLibrary" => $old[0]['isLibrary'],
    "isActive" => $old[0]['isActive'],
    "title" => $old[0]['title'],
    "nps" => $old[0]['nps'],
    "locations" => [
        "remote" => [
            "system" => $old[0]['system'],
            "system_path" => $old[0]['system_path'],  
        ],  
        "local" => [
            "system" => $old[1]['system'],
            "system_path" => $old[1]['system_path'],  
        ],  
    ],
];


var_dump($new);
```

Which outputs:

```
array(5) { 
["isLibrary"]=> int(1) 
["isActive"]=> int(1) 
["title"]=> string(11) "Mytitle1234" 
["nps"]=> int(750000001456) 
["locations"]=> array(2) { 
    ["remote"]=> array(2) { 
        ["system"]=> string(6) "Remote" 
        ["system_path"]=> string(20) "./remote/system/test" 
  } ["local"]=> array(2) { 
        ["system"]=> string(5) "Local" 
        ["system_path"]=> string(19) "./local/system/test" 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Check it in action here https://3v4l.org/rZEF3

Answer (score -1):

```
$res = [];
foreach ($test as $info) {
    $key = $info["isLibrary"] .  $info["isActive"] . $info["title"] . $info["nps"];
    if (isset($res[$key])) {
        $res[$key]['locations'][$info['system']] = [
            "system" => $info['system'],
            "system_path" => $info["system_path"],
        ];
    } else {
        $res[$key] = [
            "isLibrary" => $info["isLibrary"],
            "isActive" => $info["isActive"],
            "title" => $info["title"],
            "nps" => $info["nps"],
            "locations" => [
                $info['system'] => [
                    "system" => $info['system'],
                    "system_path" => $info["system_path"],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}

$res = array_values($res);
print_r($res);
```